# I sent Chainlink Link tokens to my ethereum address, how can I recover?

Tags: tokens, chainlink

By mistake I sent Link tokens to my ethereum wallet (kraken) that can not receive them, can I recover those tokens? How?
I think I had to swap them before sending, but I am new, and I think I made mistake. Is there a way to recover those ethereum tokens that I created?
Thanks

Comment: No. Question asked a million time. Plus it's not about ethereum itself. Voting to close.

Comment: contact the support of kraken, if they have access to the private key of the wallet then  they send can send them back, I doubt they have access to it, but an ethereum wallet can hold and transfer erc20 token

Answer (score 1):

If they are in Kraken's wallet, you have to ask them. So contact Kraken customer service to find out whether they can be retrieved.

Unfortunately, there's a big chance that they can't be recovered.

Comment: I actually have been victim of frau, as Christopher Jaszczynski, Chris MMCrypto, swaped this tokens from my ethereums, and they are invalid Link tokens, value 0.

Comment: I think it is very important , as there could not be find any other reports than mine. Now this scam is alerted to police, and it is important to widely spread that this person MMCrypto Chris is scammer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get your LINK back?
I have made the same mistake and not heard back from Kraken yet.
I will post here when I get any news.